# uncomment php/html statements within echo

Tags: php, html, echo, isset

I'm just starting to learn with some tuts and codes in php and have a problem with uncomment of php code within a echo. I hope you can help me.

Here is a the snippet of my form which i can't handle..

```html
echo '   <div class="form-group">';
echo '      <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label" for="textinput">vehicle <span class="required">*</span></label>';
echo '      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">';
echo '         <label class="radio-inline">';
echo '            <input type="radio" name="type" id="radio3" value="car"' . if (isset($_GET['id'])) {echo $row->type == "car" ? 'checked="checked"' : "";}.'> car <span class="required">*</span>';
echo '         </label>';
echo '         <label class="radio-inline">';
echo '            <input type="radio" name="type" id="radio4" value="plane"' .if (isset($_GET['id'])) {echo $row->type == "plane" ? 'checked="checked"' : "";}.'> plane <span class="required">*</span>';
echo '         </label>';
echo '      </div>';
echo '   </div>';
```

I know, the if clause is not correct. It must be something like this, right?

```
echo (isset($_GET['id'])) ? 'car' : 'not car');
```

But i dont know how to convert my isset with this example ._.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `echo 'stuff '. (isset($var) ? 'more stuff' : 'other stuff') .' stuff';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
echo '  <input type="radio" name="type" id="radio3" value="car"' . (isset($_GET['id']))?($row->type == "car" ? 'checked="checked"' : "") : "" .'> car <span class="required">*</span>';
echo '  <input type="radio" name="type" id="radio4" value="plane"' .(isset($_GET['id']))?($row->type == "plane" ? 'checked="checked"' : "") : "".'> plane <span class="required">*</span>';
```

In order to make your code more readable, you should do this:

```
<?php
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label" for="textinput">vehicle <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="radio3" value="car" <?php echo (isset($_GET['id']))?($row->type == "car" ? 'checked="checked"' : "") : "" ?> > car <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="radio4" value="plane" <?php echo (isset($_GET['id']))?($row->type == "plane" ? 'checked="checked"' : "") : "" ?> > plane <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```